# how to extract file names with .csv extension from a file

Tags: java

I am getting the file name in a string as shown below

```
s= abc.csv
```

I need to take out the abc portion of it and need to put it in sepate string

```
String r ;
```

Please advise how to put that 
I am using the below way..

```
String zipfilemove= fileCreation.split("\\.")[0]+ ".csv";
```

Comment: you need to take out `abc` and  after that append '.csv'?

Comment: You shouldn't use `split` here because a file name might have more than one period. Use the suggestion by @anubhava instead.

Answer (score 3):

`String#split(String)` uses a regx to split a String. However for your case there is no need of using regex:

```
String s = "abc.csv";
String r = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('.')); //=> abc
```

Comment: This will only work when there is one '.' in the filename.  Using s.lastIndexOf('.') would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below syntax to separate `abc` and `csv`.

```
String fileName = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('.')); // fileName will be abc
String ext = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('.')); //ext will be csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if (s.endsWith(".csv")) {
    r = s.substring(0, s.length() - 4);
}
```

You can also use regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```
    String a = "abc.csv";
    System.out.println(a.split("(\\.csv)")[0]);
```

Comment: Please! add more details